# How to test a connection to a remote SQL 2005 without SSMS?

Tags: sql-server-2005, testing, database-connection

We are having some connectivity issues from a client application connecting to a remote SQL Server 2005 (named instance).

What are some ways to test connectivity from the client machine (Windows XP) that doesn't have SSMS or Query analyzer installed?

I would like to see if the issue is related to the specific application or is it a more general connectivity to the remote sql server from the specific client.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can you create an ODBC connection via admin tools to the SQL Server and use the "Test Connection" function in there?

Comment: I'll point out that this is the only way I've found if you don't have SQL on the machine, and your sql instance has a name. Aka, `ping` and `telnet` won't always help if your instance has a name like "server-name\sql-instance-name" because while the machine may be up, the instance may not be.

Answer (score 13):

If you just want to test network connectivity, then telnet is a simple way.

telnet ip.of.sql.server 1433

Here's more in-depth information on troubleshooting connectivity issues (including using telnet)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827422

Comment: Does the telnet require username and password?

Answer (score 7):

I sometimes use the Data sources/ODBC control panel item as a "GUI" to test a DB connection.

Answer (score 3):

On windows you can create empty test.udl file and open it.
Connection wizard should appear.
It allows you to create a connection to sql server and other databases.

See this post for more details: [Test remote SQL connectivity EASILY!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/steverac/2010/12/13/test-remote-sql-connectivity-easily/)